# How to get around scala 22 fields of BsonDocument?

Tags: mongodb, scala

Because of the scala's 22 fields limit of tuples/classes i cannot create a BsonDocument that will be inserted into a mongo collection.

I thought about doing something like insert a partial document, get the _id and then update it with the other fields, but I cannot get the _id(i use the org.mongodb.scala driver).

Any idea?

Comment: what version of Scala are you using?

Comment: Even if that's not a technical limit, a single case class with more that ~20 fields could be considered as a design issue

Comment: Im using scala 2.12, so it's not and issue regarding the case class itself, but the tuple that i presume is used for the unapply

Comment: What your code for the insertion?

Comment: Can you show exactly what isn't working and what the error is?

Comment: The curious thing is that the code does not trow any error. If I add two fields in the BSONDocument(that already has the maximum of 22), then the new fields are left out.

Comment: I used insertMany because I may have batches of message to be inserted.

 def insertLogs(logs: List[HubMessageLog])(implicit ctx: CTX): Future[Completed] = {
    val documents = logs.map(getLogAsDocument) 

    mongoDBClient.database.withCollectionSO("mng.write", messageLogsCollection) { (col: MongoCollection[Document]) =>
      col.insertMany(documents, InsertManyOptions().ordered(false))
    }
  }

Comment: There must be some bug or limitation in the mongodb client library itself.

Comment: Can you post a code sample?  I have no real experience with Mongo, but I suspect they use a macro to generate a transformer between BSON and case classes (with the transformer being passed around via implicit in an example of the type class pattern).  If this is the case, it's probably not too difficult to define your own transformer for a regular (non-case) class or a tree of case classes that effectively mimics what a generated transformer for a big case class would be.